# twincat 3 het current hour (GMT+2)

Tags: twincat

I can do this (not behind plc now)

```
Hour:= (Date_to_Dint(time())+1)/3600000
```

Where I do +1 because of devision by zero errors. Though this doesn't do the GMT time part (although...I can log in and set local system time to that)
And that would all work

But I wonder isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: I mean, they have [local system time function block](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35008651.html&id=) . Further more, to modify the time zone, you can use [FB_SetTimeZoneInformation](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35022475.html&id=).

Comment: Also, if you want to avoid division by 0 implicitly, try [this](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2530362251.html&id=), in case of division by 0, the result of the calculation will be 0.